# Select one record for conditions

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a "games" table which contains `player_id` and `player_action`.

```
player_id | player_action  
1         | move  
1         | move  
1         | attack  
2         | attack  
2         | attack  
3         | move  
3         | move
```

And I have to get all player with "move" action but only one row per player,
result should looks like

```
1  |  move  
3  |  move
```

Would anyone have an idea on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you intend to do the following:

```
SELECT
    player_id, player_action
FROM
    games
WHERE
    player_action = 'move'
GROUP BY
    player_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct player_id, player_action from games where player_action = "move"
```

Comment: Does it remove also duplicates in player_action ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the DISTINCT clause:

```
SELECT DISTINCT player_id, player_action FROM games WHERE player_action = 'move';
```

The distinct clause will remove duplicate records.  (I'm sure there are many other solutions to this.)

Comment: Does it remove also duplicates in player_action ?

Comment: DISTINCT should remove any cases where the combination of *both* player_id and player_action are not unique.  (I haven't tested this specific query, but I think that is how it will behave.)  @kemp: I certainly could have made a mistake: Can you tell me what does not work?